# how to format a array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, count

i have an array `$array` that prints out something like:

```
Array
(
[Terry] => Array
    (
        [2011-10-26] => Array
            (
                [0] => 69.90
                [1] => 69.90
            )

    )

[Travis] => Array
    (
        [2011-10-26] => Array
            (
                [0] => 199.50
            )

        [2011-10-27] => Array
            (
                [0] => 199.50
            )

    )
)
```

i am trying to place data into a table like this:

```
NAME      2011-10-26     2011-10-27
Terry     2              0
Travis    1              1
```

i can get the count like this:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){  
     echo $key; // this will give me the names
     foreach($value as $keys => $values){
         echo $keys; //this will give me the dates
         echo count($values); // this will give me the count per date
     }
}
```

the dates that i get back are  like this: `2011-10-26     2011-10-26     2011-10-27`

I've been playing with this for a while and i run out of ideas.

any help?

Thanks

Comment: Are you unclear on just the date formatting, or also on how to create the table? edit: So the issue is that the dates are being returned as one large string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// build a list of all of the available dates
$dates = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $dates = array_merge($value, $dates);
}

$dates = array_keys($dates);

// You may want to sort the date columns here somehow
echo "Names\t".implode("\t",$dates)."\n";
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    echo $key;
    foreach($dates as $d){
        echo "\t".(array_key_exists($d, $value) ? count($value[$d]) : 0);
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
$days   = array();

foreach ($array as $person => &$dates)
    $days = array_merge(array_keys($dates), $days);

$days = array_unique($days);
sort($days); // Sort days.

foreach ($array as $person => &$dates) {
    foreach ($days as &$day) 
        // You can also use array_key_exists instead of '@' to suppress the notice.
        $result[$day][$person] = @count($dates[$day]);
}

var_dump($result);
```

The result:

```
array(2) {
  ["2011-10-26"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Terry"]=>
    int(2)
    ["Travis"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  ["2011-10-27"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Terry"]=>
    int(0)
    ["Travis"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```